# Count rows of a table

Tags: vba, error-handling, excel

I am trying to count the rows of two tables generated by SQL connections in Excel VBA. My plan was to use `ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count` however, this errors when a table is empty, which one often is. I found it completely impossible to use `On Error GoTo ...` twice within one `sub` so I pulled out the counts as functions like this. I based my error handling pattern on [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94462/54164). Is this the best way to go?

```
Function CountCurrencyTrades() As Integer

    Dim sheetCurrencyTable As Worksheet
    Set sheetCurrencyTable = Worksheets("CurrencyTable")

    Dim tblCurrencyTrades As ListObject
    Set tblCurrencyTrades = sheetCurrencyTable.ListObjects("CurrencyQuery")
    On Error GoTo CurrencyTradesEmpty
    CountCurrencyTrades = tblCurrencyTrades.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

CleanExit:

    Exit Function

CurrencyTradesEmpty:

    CountCurrencyTrades = 0
    Resume CleanExit

End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just some things that jump out at me:

---

### **You don't reset `OnError`**

Huge red flag right there. If you're going to change `OnError Goto` you should **immediately** write the corresponding lines to set it back to normal.

Specifically: (Square brackets for emphasis)

```
    On Error GoTo CurrencyTradesEmpty
    CountCurrencyTrades = tblCurrencyTrades.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    [On Error Goto 0] 

CleanExit:

    Exit Function

CurrencyTradesEmpty:
    [On Error Goto 0] 
    CountCurrencyTrades = 0
    Resume CleanExit
```

---

### Your function has too many responsibilities

Single Responsibility Principle. Your function has a hardcoded worksheet, hardcoded listObject and then handles the counting of said object. I would have the function take a `ListObject` as an argument and let another function handle the retrieval of said objects. Like so:

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Function GetCurrencyTradesCount() As Long

        Dim sheetCurrencyTable As Worksheet
        Set sheetCurrencyTable = Worksheets("CurrencyTable")

        Dim tblCurrencyTrades As ListObject
        Set tblCurrencyTrades = sheetCurrencyTable.ListObjects("CurrencyQuery")

        GetCurrencyTradesCount = CountListRows(tblCurrencyTrades)

    End Function

    Private Function CountListRows(ByRef targetList As ListObject) As Long
        '/ On Error (I.E. empty list), returns 0

        On Error GoTo CleanFail
        CountListRows = targetList.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        On Error GoTo 0

CleanExit:
        Exit Function

CleanFail:
        On Error GoTo 0
        CountListRows = 0
        Resume CleanExit

    End Function
```

**Scoping**

Your function is implicitly public. You should explicitly set a `Public` or `Private` scope for it.

---

**Integer**

Is officially deprecated. The compiler will silently convert all `Integer`s to `Long`s, so just use `Long` instead.

---

**Error Handling**

Do you really want your function to return 0 for all errors? What if it's given an empty object reference? I would rename your label to `CleanFail:` and think about what other failure scenarios it might want to deal with.

Comment: Can you expand on why I need the `On Error GoTo 0` and what happens if I don't have it? I agree about passing the `ListObject`.

Comment: When you change `On Error`, your change remains in effect until you change it again. Just imagine, for a second, what happens if the first line in `CleanFail:` causes an error? It would immediately jump back to the label, error again and create an infinite loop.

Comment: On `Error Goto 0` clears all manually-set error handling and resets to standard. So, **as soon** as you have executed the statement that your error handling was intended for, you should either change the error handling or reset it to normal.

Comment: Will it also reset when the function ends? i.e. is the manually-set error handling scoped to the function it is set in or is it global?

Comment: All `Err` objects (whose properties `On Error` modifies) are locally scoped within a procedure. So any `On Error` changes will only apply to the procedure they're in. N.B. though, if a sub procedure causes an error with no handling, VBA will trace its way back up the call stack until it finds an error handler. For a more complete overview, here is the [MSDN page on handling Run-Time Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193267.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the extra goto, and use inline error resetting, like this:

```
Function CountCurrencyTrades() As Integer

    Dim sheetCurrencyTable As Worksheet
    Set sheetCurrencyTable = Worksheets("CurrencyTable")

    Dim tblCurrencyTrades As ListObject
    Set tblCurrencyTrades = sheetCurrencyTable.ListObjects("CurrencyQuery")

    CountCurrencyTrades = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    CountCurrencyTrades = tblCurrencyTrades.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count    
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```