# Sub that calls itself when its parent Workbook is closed

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, ms-word, powerpoint

and no, I'm not talking about `Workbook_BeforeClose`. Note that the motivation of this question is Excel specific but the technique I'd like feedback on is not.

If you don't care about the motivation, you can skip to the chapter **Option 3, the "magic" way**.

If additionally, you already know about the `IUnknown::Release` trick, you can skip to the chapter **Implementation using `IUnknown::Release`**

I recently came across the following question on StackOverflow: [*How can i get the NOW function to update every second?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73755527/12287457)

Immediately, I thought about `Application.OnTime` and implemented a solution using this technique. I will not post the original code here as it is not what this question is about, but rather what motivated it. A simplified example of the code looks like this:

```vb
Sub KeepRecalculating()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Calculate

    Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 1, Now()), "KeepRecalculating"
End Sub
```

In principle, this solution works well and there are quite a few other questions on StackOverflow with answers that adhere to the same idea. Unfortunately, there two subtle and quite annoying drawbacks to this technique that originate in some rather interesting features of `Application.OnTime`.

Both of these issues have to do with how to cancel a task scheduled with `Application.OnTime`.

1. Enabling the solution to stop the recursive updating.

This is still quite straight forward. We need to save the planned next execution time and call `Application.OnTime` again with the additional parameter `schedule:=False`. The following code implements an additional parameter that enables the update loop to be stopped manually.

```vb
Sub KeepRecalculating(Optional ByVal schedule As Boolean = True)
    Static nextExec As Double

    Sheet1.Range("A1").Calculate
    
    If schedule Then nextExec = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())
    Application.OnTime nextExec, "KeepRecalculating", , schedule
End Sub
```

My solution also took parameters like `Range` and `updateRate` and was able to run multiple tasks simultaneously independent of each other to make it more generally applicable.

There is still the annoying fact that with this solution, pressing the `Stop` button in the VBA IDE does not stop the loop from running. A specific sub has to be called every time to stop it.

The next issue, however, is even more annoying. What if the user just closes the workbook expecting it to also stop updating? Well in this case `Application.OnTime` has a trick up its sleeve that can be a very useful feature in other situations.

2. `Application.OnTime` will reopen a closed Workbook if a macro was scheduled to run in it!

There seem to be two options to deal with this:

1. The user stops the loop manually before closing. This is very inconvenient and not really viable for most people.
2. The user adds code to the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event. This is a more reasonable option and the one I recommended in my answer on StackOverflow. It comes with the disadvantage of adding code to the `ThisWorkbook` module which is unsatisfying regarding encapsulation. It would be nice to have everything in one place.

The best option seems to be 2), yet this still comes with some drawbacks.

Firstly, the `Stop` button in the VBA IDE still can't interrupt the loop, and secondly, if the user for some reason had set `Application.EnableEvents = False`, the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event would never be called and the loop would have to be interrupted manually.

While both of these are not huge issues, it would still be nice to overcome them. When I asked [@CristianBuse](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/227582/cristian-buse) about this, I got a hint that opened the door to some hacking, making all of this possible.

### Option 3, the "magic" way

I'm talking about the `IUnknown::Release` trick.

The code to produce all of this magical behavior looks like this:

```vb
#If Mac Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#End If

Public Sub Release(ByVal instancePtr As LongPtr)
    MsgBox "Magic!"
End Sub

'If the Sub Main gets executed, Release will be called once the object containing
'this code gets terminated or the VBA environment is reset (e.g. Stop button)
Sub Main()
    Static o As IUnknown
    Static vtbl(0 To 2) As LongPtr, vtblPtr As LongPtr
    
    If vtblPtr = 0 Then
       vtbl(2) = VBA.Int(AddressOf Release)
       vtblPtr = VarPtr(vtbl(0))
       CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(o), VarPtr(vtblPtr), LenB(vtblPtr)
    End If
End Sub
```

This code works by creating a "fake" object of type `IUnknown` and hooking into its `Release` method.

A static variable of type `IUnknown` is declared and a fake virtual method table is inserted. The virtual method table can point to three methods:

1. `IUnknown::AddRef`, called whenever the instances reference counter is incremented
2. `IUnknown::QueryInterface`, called whenever information about the object's interface is required
3. `IUnknown::Release`, called whenever the instances reference counter is decremented

For the above-described problem, the `Release` method seems very, very interesting. Once `Main` was called, `Release` will be called, whenever the object `o`'s reference count gets decremented. Because o is static and we don't create other instances, this happens in three cases:

1. When the function containing it gets recompiled. (Excel will crash)
2. When the `Stop` button in the VBA-IDE is pressed.
3. When the Workbook is closed.

The two latter cases are **exactly** what we need! The first one is not really a problem as long as the function isn't touched while `o` is active.

### Implementation of the original problem using `IUnknown::Release`

The obvious (and probably best) way to implement this is as follows:

```vb
#If Mac Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#End If

Public Sub Release(ByVal instancePtr As LongPtr)
    KeepRecalculating schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub SetIUnknown()
    Static isSet As Boolean: If isSet Then Exit Sub
    
    Static o As IUnknown
    Static vtbl(0 To 2) As LongPtr, vtblPtr As LongPtr
    
    If vtblPtr = 0 Then
       vtbl(2) = VBA.Int(AddressOf Release)
       vtblPtr = VarPtr(vtbl(0))
       CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(o), VarPtr(vtblPtr), LenB(vtblPtr)
    End If
    
    isSet = True
End Sub

Sub KeepRecalculating(Optional ByVal schedule As Boolean = True)
    Static nextExec As Double
    
    SetIUnknown
    
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Calculate
    
    If schedule Then nextExec = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())
    Application.OnTime nextExec, "KeepRecalculating", , schedule
End Sub
```

This works beautifully. Clicking `Stop` in the IDE stops the loop, closing the Workbook stops the loop, even if `Application.EnableEvents = False`. This trick is not application specific, just a little bit hacky. In the above example, only `Application.OnTime` and `Range.Calculate` are Excel-specific. The trick could also be useful in other contexts in other applications.

My first question is:

Is this approach viable? It's a bit hacky, for example placing a breakpoint inside the `Release` method or anything called through it crashes the Application. This would be no problem in "production", are there other issues? I can't see any.

### Venturing further into the possibilities

Bad habits led me to perform further experiments on the limits of this method.

Because of the VBA-IDEs inability to organize larger amounts of modules, I sometimes seek to implement certain features in a single procedure.

I like the portability of having one blob of code without dependencies, which I can just copy into a module and use. This way, the amount of modules in actual projects stays small, and navigating the code is easier.

Knowing about the drawbacks of this habit, but fueled by a certain curiosity I wondered if it was possible to implement all of the above-described functionality in a single procedure.

As it turned out, yes it is.

I will not post the entire subroutine here, as it contains a lot of irrelevant fluff. For those interested, it can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/f248271da14d40a6ec7b44ccca245479). If you insist on critiquing it I won't object since this is CodeReview but please know that I'm well aware of its terrible style and utter unreadability in its current form. My goal was to create a magic blob of code, its usefulness was questionable from the beginning.

The following `Sub` showcases the essence of the technique.

```vb
#If Mac Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#End If

Public Sub KeepRecalculating(Optional ByRef Range As Object = Nothing, _
                             Optional ByRef refreshTimeSeconds As Long = 1&, _
                             Optional ByRef schedule As Boolean = True, _
                             Optional ByRef stopAll As Boolean = False)
    Static o As IUnknown '<--- this MUST be the first static variable allocated!
    Static vtbl(0 To 2) As LongPtr, vtblPtr As LongPtr
    
    If vtblPtr = 0 Then
       vtbl(2) = VBA.Int(AddressOf KeepRecalculating)
       vtblPtr = VarPtr(vtbl(0))
       CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(o), VarPtr(vtblPtr), LenB(vtblPtr)
    End If
    
    Static nextExec As Double, isSet As Boolean
#If Win64 Then  'Detect if sub was called as "Release":
    If VarPtr(o) = VarPtr(schedule) Then
#Else
    If VarPtr(o) = VarPtr(stopAll) Then
#End If
        If Not isSet Then Exit Sub
        Application.OnTime nextExec, "KeepRecalculating", , False
        Exit Sub 'Exit Sub if called as "Release" to prevent accessing of parameters
    End If 'The Subs parameters MUST NOT be accessed before this line!

    Sheet1.Range("A1").Calculate
    
    If schedule Then nextExec = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())
    Application.OnTime nextExec, "KeepRecalculating", , schedule
    isSet = True
End Sub
```

You may notice that this function has a bunch of parameters that go practically unused. In my original solution, I need all of these parameters and more, here they are just necessary to showcase the method.

Safely implementing parameters for this function is actually the crux of this entire problem. `IUnknown::Release` only expects one `ByVal` argument, the instance pointer. We now want a function with completely different parameters to be called in place of `Release`.

There are certain implications that come with this. During the automatic `Release` call, all of the parameters now defined point to the memory occupied by the `ByVal instancePtr` argument, or the memory next to it on the stack frame.

Because the parameters now essentially point to memory having nothing to do with their type, accessing them in any way assuming their type will crash the Application. This of course includes copying them, the reason why the parameters **must** be `ByRef`.

Of course, we'd like to use the arguments inside the `Sub`. In order to do this, the `Sub` must have a way of "knowing" it was called as the fake `Release` method and exit before accessing any of the arguments. This can be achieved by examining the memory passed to the optional parameters when called as `Release`. A way to do this is as follows:

```vb
    Debug.Print "Pointer of the object:"
    Debug.Print VarPtr(o) '<-- VarPtr of the Static object  (instancePtr!)
    
    Debug.Print "Memory passed into parameters:"
    Debug.Print VarPtr(Range)                '<-- First parameter
    Debug.Print VarPtr(refreshTimeSeconds)
    Debug.Print VarPtr(schedule)             '<-- instancePtr on x64
    Debug.Print VarPtr(stopAll)              '<-- instancePtr on x86
    Debug.Print VarPtr(param5)
    Debug.Print VarPtr(param6)
    Debug.Print VarPtr(param7)
    Debug.Print VarPtr(param8)
```

Note that accessing the variables like this does not assume their type, doesn't lead to a `QueryInterface` call, and hence doesn't crash the application.

Running this test will reveal, that the actual memory containing `instancePtr` seems to align with the third parameter `schedule` in 64-bit and the fourth parameter `stopAll` in 32-bit applications.

The memory before that (parameter 1 and 2) seems to be something related to the implementation of the `ByVal` argument, and the memory after seems to be `Null` followed by random stuff.

Interestingly, the equality of e.g. `VarPtr(schedule) = VarPtr(o)` on x64, does **only hold if `o` is the first `Static` variable declared in the `Sub`**. Declaring other `Static` variables before will create an offset between `VarPtr(o)` and VarPtr(schedule) equal to the number of bytes declared before `o`.

If `o` is not declared `Static` but just regular with `Dim`, there seems to be a base offset of 8 between the two values `VarPtr(schedule)` and `VarPtr(o)`, and in this case, every regularly `Dim`'d variable before `o` seems to create an offset in the other direction than in the `Static` case.

My testing seems to suggest, however, that as long as `o` is `Static` and declared as the first variable, there is no offset and the equality does hold. This can be used to recognize that the `Sub` was called as the `Release` method and therefore we can exit the `Sub` before actually accessing any of the parameters.

Because I have little understanding of the underlying workings of VBA, I'm interested in how all of these observed behaviors can be explained.

I'd like to know if using this admittedly quite hacky technique bears too many risks or if, henceforth, I can assume it is reliable enough to actually be used.

Are there any risks of having the `ByRef` parameters point to random memory as long as it can be assured that they will not be touched while doing so?

Does the condition I'm using to detect the `Release` call hold reliably or was I just "lucky"?

Comment: Do you want reviews of all these functions, or just one of them?  BTW, you are expected to know how your code works; asking for explanation is specifically [outside the scope](/help/dont-ask) of Code Review.

Comment: Hello @TobySpeight. As I thought I clearly indicated in my post, I am asking for review of the last two functons. I know that my code works and approximately how it works. I thought questions like: Is this approach viable? Are there Risks? Which are the essence of my above post, are exactly what Code Review is for. While I don't understand exactly what bytecode the VBA compiler produces, I don't think that is a reasonable criterion since very few people outside of Microsoft do..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @TobySpeight, if you think these questions are not open-ended enough I'm open to moving this post to StackOverflow, but I'm not sure if it would be more on-topic there since the code already works and some of the questions would probably be considered "opinion based".

Comment: I think this is the right place; I skim-read it initially and picked on trigger phrases such as "how ... can be explained" etc.  It's a language I've never used, so I'm not really in a position to review it myself, so I'll leave it to the experts in [tag:vba] to give you reviews or suggest changes to how it's presented.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Release` magic trick is dangerous because it can mess with the underlying `EbMode` function used by VB to determine if code is running or not.

To replicate, run `Main` as presented in the question under the **Option 3, the "magic" way** section. Here is the same code for convenience:

```
Option Explicit

#If Mac Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#End If

Public Sub Release(ByVal instancePtr As LongPtr)
    MsgBox "Magic!"
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Static o As IUnknown
    Static vtbl(0 To 2) As LongPtr, vtblPtr As LongPtr
    
    If vtblPtr = 0 Then
       vtbl(2) = VBA.Int(AddressOf Release)
       vtblPtr = VarPtr(vtbl(0))
       CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(o), VarPtr(vtblPtr), LenB(vtblPtr)
    End If
End Sub
```

After running `Main` run any method and reset state while code is still running. Here are 2 ways:

1. Run this:

```
Sub Boom()
    End
End Sub
```

Or:

2. Run this:

```
Sub Boom2()
    Stop
End Sub
```

and when the code breaks on the `Stop` line, press the Reset button in the IDE:

[image: Reset]

Although, state was lost, the Locals window will show "Running":

[image: Running]

and now VBA has gone 'crazy' as there is no way to step through code anymore or run other macros until the whole Application is restarted.

---

In short, using this trick directly or via the Sub that calls itself is:

- safe, if state is lost while no code is running
- unsafe, if state is lost while code is running and Application needs restarting

---

Alternatively, I've created the [StateLossCallback](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-StateLossCallback) class that is:

- safe, if state is lost while no code is running
- safe, but does nothing (callback not called), if state is lost while code is running

Comment: That is very insightful, thanks a lot! Probably explains some weird behavior I have seen when testing back then, but I was never able to put the finger on what was actually going on.

Comment: @GWD Thanks! When we first discussed this, I was not aware of this issue either. Thankfully, someone raised an issue [here](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-StateLossCallback/issues/1) and only then I've realized what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative suggestion too long for a comment. I wrote code to use WinAPI timers:  [Tick. Tick. *breathe* BOOM! - Setting up real, stable asynchronous callbacks with WinAPI Timers in VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/229656/146810)

These can be used to call a method which may be:

- Stopped with the stop button
- Disabled when Excel closes
- Even stopped with the End statement
- Can handle Errors and launch debugger (just make sure to continue execution after)

#### Standard Module

```
Option Explicit

Sub StartContinuousRecalculating()
    Dim cellToRecalc As Range
    Set cellToRecalc = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    'spawn a new timer instance, it will call "RecalculateCellProc" supplying the Data argument as the userData param
    ' i.e. it will forward the cell reference to the proc every time it is called
    TickerAPI.StartManagedTimer New RecalculateCellProc, delaymillis:=1000, Data:=cellToRecalc
End Sub
```

#### Class `RecalculateCellProc`

```
Option Explicit

Implements Timing.ITimerProc

Private Sub ITimerProc_Exec(ByVal timerID As LongPtr, ByVal userData As Variant, ByVal tickCount As Long)
    'Doesn't matter if we raise errors here as this is a managed timer proc, error details are logged
    'Can even set breakpoints as long as we don't click `End` during a callback, that will crash Excel
    userData.Calculate 'assume it's the range we're expecting
End Sub
```

Obviously this isn't commentary on your approach. You just may want to do it this way since it is a bit less hacky (e.g. allows breakpoints/errors, doesn't use state machine logic that's hard to follow), and you can have finer grained control over what you call and millisecond delays.

---

*CristianBuse created [another great approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/274652/146810) to these timers using 1 workbook that spawns another delegate workbook to handle the WinAPI calls with an extra degree of safety. His approach is even more stable/harder to crash - you have to set a breakpoint in the second workbook I think. But it's a bit more overhead (which may or may not be an issue for you) and Excel specific IIUC and it sounds like you want host-agnostic code.*

Comment: I have heard of your work on timers before but only skim-read it so far! This has the big advantage of being cross-application but the disadvantage of being Windows only. Without having looked into it in detail though, I think if working in Excel and not requiring sub-1-second resolution (or requiring stopping on `End` which would indicate other problems in the code anyways), `Application.OnTime` with the `IUnknown` trick makes more sense. It requires way less code and seems to be similar stability-wise. (Of course, I mean the version where `SetIUnknown` and `Release` are separate procedures..

Comment: "More code" isn't exactly the issue - it's more that if copy+paste is your distribution method, then portability is a concern. If you distribute a self extracting zip, or using a package manager (or RD sync) those issues go away. Plus you get the benefit of being able to update the code. If cross-platform compatibility is an issue, I'd just implement `Application.OnTime` as an  `ITimerProvider` https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMLJB.png . Stability-wise there is a difference between "I can't set a breakpoint or it'll crash" vs "I can set breakpoints but cannot prematurely exit the Sub or it'll crash"

Comment: What I'm trying to say is context is key. So I agree with your view if, copy+paste, single-use code, long timer delay are your assumptions. But if nice API, high performance low-overhead, addin distribution is your approach I'd just ship with a Timing.xlam dependency. And if you are editing and debugging, Cristian Buse's code is the safest, but likely a bit more overhead setting up that second workbook.

Comment: I should actually incorporate Cristian's code as a "StableTimerProvider" or something, for developing in Excel and then you switch to release mode and use the raw API...

Comment: You are of course right, more code is not a problem per se. I usually distribute .xlsm files and don't use add ins, which is why I like Cristians way of providing libraries (as standard modules)... And I have to point out that this method doesn't crash on breakpoints **unless** called as `Release`, which is usually a small minority of all the calls...